# Script codecept handling the __exec_command event returned with error code 255

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, composer-php, codeception

I am very new to unit testing and have been trying to use codeception to do it. So I have followed the following guidelines [link](https://codeception.com/for/laravel)
and installed it using composer: `composer require "codeception/codeception" --dev`, it was successful, but when I tried to set it up using `composer exec codecept bootstrap` I got the following error:

> Script codecept handling the __exec_command event returned with error
>   code 255

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Just FYI, I have pulled the whole project from a repo that already has the tests/unit folder with previous tests already.

My composer.json file has the following

```
    "require": {
        "codeception/robo-paracept": "dev-master",
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "codeception/codeception": "2.6.x-dev",
```

Comment: Run `./vendor/bin/codecept bootstrap` to get a better error message.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue was with the php version that I was using. I am using 7.3; using 7.2 solved my problem and the whole thing went smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command with the `-v` option to show verbose output.
In my case there where unallowed tabs in my *tests/functional.suite.yml* file.
I replaced them with 4 spaces and everything was fine.